# <Figure> not displaying in <div> container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new at react and am trying to build an app from a tutorial. I used the figure tag in the component but cannot see it in inspect element of chrome. Here are the codes.

The  container in tutorial has  tag as child. I am not getting that

[Image from the tutorial containing div tag with figure tag as child element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMl7J.jpg)

[My code with only div tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuhXc.jpg)

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './Components/Main'
import './styles/stylesheet.css'



ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Title from './Title'
import Photowall from './Photowall'
const posts = [{
id: "0",
description: "beautiful landscape",
imageLink: "https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i4eeacaa2dbf12d6d/version/1490299332/most-beautiful-landscapes-in-europe-lofoten-european-best-destinations-copyright-iakov-kalinin.jpg" +
"3919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
},

{
id: "1",
 description: "Aliens???", imageLink: "https://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/rocket.jpg"
}, 

{
id: "2",
 description: "On a vacation!",imageLink: "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/24/104670887-VacationExplainsTHUMBWEB.1910x1000.jpg"
}

class Main extends Component{
render(){
return <div>
          <Title title={'Photowall'}/>
          <Photowall posts={posts}/>
        </div>
}

}
export default Main
```

Photowall.js

```
import React,{ Component} from 'react'
import Photo from './Photo'
class Photowall extends Component{
render() {
return

    <div className='photo-grid'>
        {this.props.posts.map((post,index)=> <Photo key={index} post={post}/>)}
    </div>

  }
  }
export default Photowall
```

Photo.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Photo extends Component{
render(){
const post =this.props.post
return <figure className="figure"></figure>

}
}
export default Photo
```

Stylesheet.js

```
html{
font-size: 10px;
}
h1{
font-family: billabong;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13rem;
margin: 2rem 0rem;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 4px;
color: grey;
}

@font-face {
font-family: billabong;
src: url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/13949/Billabong.woff') format('woff');
}
.photo-grid {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.figure {
flex-basis: calc (33.333%-4rem);
border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
padding: 2rem;
flex-grow: 1;
margin: 0 2rem;   
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

#### Your Photowall HTML is dead code

Seems like your enitre `Photowall` component is not rendering itself.

The problem is that your HTML is not on the same line as `return` (becoming dead code).

If you put your HTML below your `return` is like you are returning undefined so the component doesn't render nothing.

---

You should always put your first HTML line right after `return` , not some line below.

```
class Photowall extends Component{
  render() {
    return <div className='photo-grid'>
          {this.props.posts.map((post,index)=> <Photo key={index} post={post}/>)}
       </div>
  }
}
```

or wrapping your html between brakets (more readable in my opinion)

```
class Photowall extends Component{
  render() {
    return ( // starting from the same line as return
       <div className='photo-grid'>
          {this.props.posts.map((post,index)=> <Photo key={index} post={post}/>)}
       </div>
   )
  }
}
```